Performance Issue with Feature Layer while using "@arcgis/core": "=4.28.10“ Library
We were using an older version of the ArcGIS JavaScript API, specifically @types/arcgis-js-api: 4.8.0. With this version, we didn't encounter any performance issues.
Recently, we upgraded to @arcgis/core: 4.28.10 instead of @types/arcgis-js-api: 4.8.0. After the upgrade, we noticed the following:

In production, the response time from the Point and Polygon AGOL Layers has significantly slowed down, taking 30-40 seconds to respond.
The response format in the latest version of the ArcGIS API has changed to f=pbf, and multiple requests are being sent with different extent geometries.
In the older version, the response format was f=json, and only a single request was sent to fetch all the data without any extent geometry.

We are displaying Point and Polygon features using the FeatureLayer with definitionExpression and renderer properties. We are not using the GraphicLayer to render symbols on the map.
Do you have any suggestions? Are we missing something in the upgrade process?
For now, we've reverted to the older ArcGIS API version (@types/arcgis-js-api: 4.8.0) since we couldn't resolve the issue.

We are using "@arcgis/core": "^4.30.9". It works fine. No delay in response from Point or  Polygon. Try this version.
